# Html wrap word to next line?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with below content.

```
hai hello ho
w are you wh
ere are you?
```

But I want the word to appear in next line instead of breaking as below.

```
hai hello 
how are you 
where are 
you?
```

What **CSS** style do I need to apply?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap them in some `<p>` tags (even though that's not CSS).

Comment: Presumably if you see that remove `word-break:break-all`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following ccs:

```
.wrap {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 100px;
}
```

With the following html:

```
<div class="wrap"> 
    hai hello how are you where are you?
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Using `<br>` , but this is not professional way

```html
<p>
  hai hello
  <br>how are you
  <br>where are
  <br>you?
</p>
```

2. Using `max-width`

```css
p {
  max-width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hai hello how are you where are you?
</p>
```

rest of the methods are using jQuery/JavaScript, But I don't suggest you to include JS for this :)

Comment: Actually, this is ok solution. Solutions with setting widths and css - doesn't work same in all browsers, especially when more exotic fonts are there....

Comment: What else would you like to suggest me? If you know, please let me know too :)

Comment: No, i just said that <br> is good enough in cases like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put it in

```
<p>
```

tags and if you want to make sure it won't break mid-word with CSS use the style of

```
word-wrap:normal
```

on your paragraph, although the p tag alone should do it for you